# I want to add only one file that already contains in master branch to other branch?(GIT)

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have branch master in GIT and there are a few files.

I want to add only one file from that branch to another, how to do that?

Can not find any info among the internet.

Comment: git checkout -b yournewbranch; git add yourfile; git commit -m "only one file added, see git add command"

Comment: but there will all other files from master and this also,  i want only this file in this branch from master without other, for example i have lesson_1 , lesson_2 and i want there will be only file from lesson_1 without lesson_2

Comment: Do you mean to copy the content of one file to another branch? Or do you want a branch with all other files deleted?

Comment: First question is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```bash
git checkout <file-destination-branch>
git checkout master -- <file-to-get-from-master-branch>
git add <file-to-get-from-master>
git commit -m "Got file from master branch"
```

Comment: pathspec 'src/main/java/com/lesson_1/Lesson1.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.  Why is this so?( Would it be the problem if i have already pushed them?

Comment: `git add` should not be required here, checking out a file at a revision will automatically update the index (but it doesn't hurt to call `add`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `git checkout` command.

Step 1: go to the branch containing the file (`$ git checkout <branch containing the file>`)

Step 2: run `$ git checkout <branch to move the file to> <file>`

For more info, run `$ git -h checkout`